# Python beautifulsoup - getting input value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've got many table rows like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="123599"></td>
</tr>
```

Iterate with:

```
table = BeautifulSoup(response).find(id="sometable") # Make soup.

for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]: # Find rows.
    cells = row.find_all("td") # Find cells.

    points = int(cells[0].get_text())
    gold = int(cells[1].get_text())
    id = cells[2].input['value']

    print id
```

Error:

```
File "./script.py", line XX, in <module>
id = cells[2].input['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How can I get input value? I don't want to use regexp.

Comment: It looks like for at least one of your rows, there is no input tag in the third cell. Please provide the whole markup, or catch the error and have it print the row.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is notoriously fragile. Better use lxml or lxml.html.

Comment: @Will: You're correct, I miss that. There's a one row without input tag. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 68):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
try:
    value = soup.find('input', {'id': 'xyz'}).get('value')
except Exception as e:
    print("Got unhandled exception %s" % str(e))
```

Comment: Works great for identifying tags based on other unique attributes, such as     `soup.find('input', {'name': 'abc'}).get('value')`

Comment: What if there are no `id`, like `<input onclick="move(this);" type="checkbox" value="007"`?