# Extracting a value from a HTML string (PYTHON)

Tags: python, html, email, variables, split

I'm having some trouble extracting some data from this string:

```
<input class="mail-address-address" id="mailAddress" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="THE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE"/>).
```

How could I store the `value=` into my own variable? I've thought about splitting but don't think you can split a whole word. Could you split at a certain char by `.count()` method? Thank you, hopefully I could get some help on this.
Thanks

EDIT:

I'm trying to get the id by converting it to HTML since splinter did not seem to get the content in ID (it was just blank)

```
site = "https://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html?dswid=9902"
req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
address-address" id="mailAddress" readonly="readonly">')
find = soup.find("class", {"id": "mailAddress"})
findId = soup.find(id="mailAddress")
```

the variable findId prints this:

```
<input class="mail-address-address" id="mailAddress" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="cblahblah@mvrht.com"/>)
```

@Sidney

```
html_line= '''<input class="mail-address-address" id="mailAddress" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="cblahblah@mvrht.com"/>)'''
input_value=html_line.split('value="',1)[1].rsplit('"',1)[0]
print(input_value)
```

This works fine except the domain name changes. ''' means I can't use my own variable (findId). Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Give some more context. Where is this string from? Is this from your own site?

Comment: For this simple case you can use a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really use an html parser to parse html (not a regex or string manipulation).  For example, you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

first, install the package:

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

then use it to to grab the value from your input tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
val = soup.input['value']  # val now contains the string 'THE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE'
print(val)
```

Comment: Since there are more than one ID in the HTML of the code, it outputs the first ID which is languageForm. Is there a way we can specify this to: findId = soup.find(id="mailAddress") which prints <input class="mail-address-address" id="mailAddress" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="cblahblah@mvrht.com"/>)

Answer (score 2):

As @Daniel Roseman says, it would be nice to have some more context. Normally when parsing HTML you can use libraries like `BeautifulSoup`. A good example for your case is [Python beautifulsoup - getting input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691271/python-beautifulsoup-getting-input-value).

If you want to code your own parser, or if you need something simple, you can even use `split()`:

```
html_line='''<input class="mail-address-address" id="mailAddress" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="THE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE"/>)'''
input_value=html_line.split('value="',1)[1].rsplit('"',1)[0]
```

I'd better advice you to use `BeautifulSoup` (and if you wan't a simple parser, better use @sidney's answer)

Answer (score 2):

This would be pretty messy to handle using `.split()`, so I would suggest using regular expressions (if you choose not to use HTML parsing libraries). To use regex, you need to import the `re` module, and use the following regular expression, `" +value=\"(.*?)\""`, like so:

```
import re
yourString = '<input class="mail-address-address" id="mailAddress" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="THE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE"/>'

# m is the match object, containing data about the regex search.
m = re.search(" +value=\"(.*?)\"", yourString)

# To retrieve the content captured inside the parentheses inside the regex, look for saved matches.
value = m.group(1)
```

The regex searches for:

- one or more spaces, followed directly by,
- the literal string `value="`, followed directly by,
- zero or more of any characters, searched non-greedily (this is so that the regex match doesn't keep searching after it encounters the end of the value). This bit is what we're looking to store.
- a closing `"`