# Get value from a list using BS4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using BS4 to parse a website to extract some part numbers and details.
I can find the class 'manufDetaiList' which contains the values I am trying to retrieve from the site.  I am unable to then retrieve the actual values though from these fields:
pdpProductBrandName - Stronghand Tools
pdpProductSKUvalue -02139254
pdpProductMPN -MST327

I have read a number of BS4 starting tutorials, but I can not find something to help extract the values as required.

```
In [11]:page.find_all (class_= 'manufDetailList')
Out[11]: [<div class="manufDetailList">
  <ul>
 <li>Stronghand Tools</li>
 <input name="pdpProductBrandName" type="hidden" value="Stronghand Tools"/>
 <li>BW#:<span class="hobsondata">02139254</span></li>
 <input name="pdpProductSKU" type="hidden" value="02139254"/>
 <li>Mfr#:<span class="hobsondata">MST327</span></li>
 <input name="pdpProductMPN" type="hidden" value="MST327"/>
 <input name="categoryName" type="hidden" value="Tools - Hand, Measuring &amp; Precision/Clamps – Magnetic/Corner – Pre Tooling"/>
 <li>UNSPSC#:<span class="hobsondata">27112121</span></li>
 </ul>
 </div>]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python beautifulsoup - getting input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691271/python-beautifulsoup-getting-input-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `value` attribute and can match the required element(s) using the `name` attribute

```
soup.select_one('[name="pdpProductBrandName"]')['value']
```

Same idea for each of the others.

You could add the parent class if required

```
soup.select_one('.manufDetailList [name="pdpProductBrandName"]')['value']
```

Read about css attribute selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). The `[]` represent attribute selector.

Comment: Thankyou Qharr,  Your answer helped me understand how to return an answer using two attributes to look it up.