# Parse html value in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have following html:

```
<td>
   <input maxlen="1" name="db" size="1" type="text" value="25"/>
   <div style="display:inline-block;position:relative;top:6px;left:0px;width:20px;">
    <input class="p_b" name="ta" style="height:1em; width:1.5em;line-height:1em;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;background-color:#f3f3f3" type="submit" value="▴"/>
    <input class="p_b" name="ta" style="height:1em; width:1.5em;line-height:1em;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;background-color:#f3f3f3" type="submit" value="▾"/>
   </div>
   <span style="position:relative;top:8px">
    
   </span>
   <input maxlen="1" name="dc" size="1" type="text" value="0"/>
   <div style="display:inline-block;position:relative;top:6px;left:0px;width:20px;">
    <input class="p_b" name="tb" style="height:1em; width:1.5em;line-height:1em;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;background-color:#f3f3f3" type="submit" value="▴"/>
    <input class="p_b" name="tb" style="height:1em; width:1.5em;line-height:1em;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;background-color:#f3f3f3" type="submit" value="▾"/>
   </div>
  </td>
```

I need to extract both numbers from value="25" and value="0".
I made a workaround like:

```
y = soup.findAll('input', {'type':'text'})
a = re.findall('(?<=value=")(\d*)',str(y))
```

But I think there is should be more direct way to do it via parser, can anyone help with it?

Comment: I'd use an XPath approach.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup) post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python beautifulsoup - getting input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691271/python-beautifulsoup-getting-input-value)

Comment: @MetallimaX BeautifulSoup doesn't suport XPath

Comment: @Parolla I know and you don't have to stick to it either. XPath has been done for those kind of queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code line to extract `@value` from each input node

```
values = [element['value'] for element in soup.findAll('input', {'type':'text'})]
```

P.S. Note that using regex for web-scraping is a very bad practice - there are enough web-scraping tools that can easily do this for you (for instance, [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [lxml](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) can be used in Python)