# Get specific value from HTML code in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, finance

Im using Bs4 to get a value from the website: https://site.financialmodelingprep.com/weighted-average-cost-of-capital/AAPL

I want to obtain the value in the row "Wacc".

I have managed to retrieve the line of "code" in which the value is, but can i extract this exact number (ie. 7.34)?

```
<td class="align-right"><input class="input-percent" id="wacc" type="number" value="7.34"/>
```

I believe this is an easy question for most of you, and it might even seem banal, however I can simply not find the answer myself.

Comment: Or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691271/python-beautifulsoup-getting-input-value

Comment: Various google searches came up with these hits that already answer your question.

Comment: A comment within one of your suggestions resultet in the desired solution. I truly appreciate your help!